# Oracle 12C boolean Variable initialization issue

Tags: java, oracle12c

I am little new to Oracle store procedure development, i am facing a problem with boolean variable initialization  in Oracle 12C version, the same piece of code works fine in Oracle 11G. Could you please help me identifying the problem if it has any.

Piece of Code  from Store Procedure:

```
IF v_Delivery_End_Dttm IS NULL THEN
    IF v_Spl_Instr_Code_1 = 'L' THEN
        g_Launch_Orders := TRUE;
    ELSIF v_Spl_Instr_Code_1 IS NULL THEN
        g_Regular_Orders := TRUE;
    END IF;
ELSIF (v_Delivery_End_Dttm IS NOT NULL AND ( v_Spl_Instr_Code_1 = 'L' OR v_Spl_Instr_Code_1 IS NULL )) THEN
    g_CRDD_Orders := TRUE;
END IF;

       Input Values:- are 
       v_Delivery_End_Dttm is nulll
       v_Spl_Instr_Code_1  is null
       g_Launch_Orders, g_Regular_Orders, g_CRDD_Orders are global variables and they are initialized to FALSE in Packed Body Variable initailization part.
       And  the global variables are initialized to TRUE in only above mentioned code.
       In Oracle 12C at a time two globales are becoming TRUE, and that to doesn't happen all  the time, For the same data it  initialized properly  at some time and it doesn't at some other time.

          From the above example i have the output as below
            g_Launch_Orders = FALSE
            g_Regular_Orders = TRUE
            g_CRDD_Orders = TRUE
```

ideally i should have only g_Regular_Orders  becoming TRUE, but g_CRDD_Orders  was also initialized to TRUE. This is happening only  in ORACLE 12C and it working fine in ORACLE 11G.

Could you please let me know if you find anything wrong in the above piece of code or is there any bug in ORACLE12C.

By the way i  invoke the Stored procedure from Java

Any help is much apppreciated

Thanks,
Ramakrishna

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to say what is wrong with your code without of initialization section. To be sure that a variable have value you need, initialize it:

```
procedure my_proc(....) is
  my_bool1 boolean := true;   -- this variable will have value "TRUE"
  my_bool2 boolean := false;  -- this variable will have value "FALSE"
begin
  ...
end;
```

This code will work the same way in both your oracle versions.

Comment: Thanks Mate, In Initialization Section i did initialized the values with "FALSE" for  all the three variables  g_Launch_Orders, g_Regular_Orders, g_CRDD_Orders